# Read a value from a cell without opening the Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have this `workbook (30 000 Ko)` and its a pain to open it and then take a cell value and also takes time **A LOT OF TIME**, i did this

```
 Set File = Workbooks.Open("lala\lolo\lili\thisfile.xlsm")
 Qty = File.Worksheets("page.").Range("S41").Value

 File.Close
```

Is there a way to take this value without THE `WORKBOOKS.OPEN FUNCTION` something fast.

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

---

Just an edit for some reason i can't answer my own question well i found an answer, in the comments.

Comment: Is it always the same cell in the same worksheet??

Comment: Yes, its always the same cell and the same workbook

Comment: Found it ,

First of all you need the R1C1 reference to your cell that you want.

Then just do this :

    MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("'G:\LOLO\LALA\Path\[YourWorkBook.xlsm]NameofThePage'!R41C19")
The R41C19 is the R1C1 reference to S41 (The cell i want) And it works For me **at least**